# Stop Advanced Python Scheduler Job After Closing Terminal

Tags: python, terminal, scheduler, jobs, shutdown

**Background**

I launched several jobs using the Advanced Python Scheduler (APScheduler) using code similar to the one below.

```
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()
sched.add_interval_job(function, minutes=1)
sleep(10000)
sched.shutdown()
```

I did this from the terminal.

```
python script.py
```

**Problem**

I intended for the jobs to be run a large number of times before shutting down. Unfortunately, I accidentally closed the terminal during their `sleep` stages, before the jobs could be stopped appropriately with `sched.shutdown()`.

I believe the jobs are still running in the background as I have evidence that the `function` has been applied even after the terminals were closed.

**Question**

Is there any way to identify which jobs are still running somewhere in the background and shut them down? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the process is still running after you closed the terminal, it should still run to completion and shutdown gracefully. If the process aborted, then your jobs aborted as well (because they run in-process). Which one is it?

Comment: @shx2, the process did not abort. I closed the terminal. Is there a way to shut it down manually rather than waiting for the scheduled shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the process id and kill the process using `kill <PID>`, or simply `pkill -f script.py`.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your script like:

```
python scrip.py
```

after you close the terminal, python process will be killed, so your script stop running.

But if you run your script with &

```
python scrip.py &
```

process will be not killed after terminal close, and you can check it using

```
ps -e | grep python
```

You have to understand different between jobs and system process. Closing the terminal kills the process. If you want check which jobs are still working, you can use print_jobs() function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did not include `&` when I ran the script, but the `ps` command you suggest identifies one python process: `673 ttys002    0:00.00 grep python`.